# Automatically login to Django app using Microsoft account after logging in to Outlook 365

Tags: python, django, microsoft-graph-api, office365, django-allauth

I have a DJango application called "tools". Then I have a second application called "users" which is for user management. When logging in, you can start both with the username and password, as well as with Microsoft. I have done this with "django-allauth". Works correctly. I want to implement SSO. That is, if I am logged in to "outlook365", when I enter my web page I want to automatically log in without me having to go to the login page. How can I do it taking into account that I already logged in correctly with the microsoft account? I WANT THE USER TO NOT HAVE TO HIT THE "login" BUTTON BUT AUTOMATICALLY WHEN I ENTER "/" THE ACCOUNT IS CONNECTED

I understand that it has to be done through cookies, that's why in my view I have this:

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('main_page')

    if request.COOKIES.get('OutlookSession'):
        print ("COOKIES")
        session_cookie_value = request.COOKIES['OutlookSession']
        user = authenticate(request, auth_entry='microsoft', your_cookie_parameter=session_cookie_value)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('main_page')

    print("No")
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

To the console it just prints "No", so it doesn't go into the condition. But if I look in the inspection part -> applications -> cookies I get this:

```
        dev-tools.mondragonlingua.com   /   Sesión  3                   Medium  
csrftoken   y6CCpdas759tas34wIfxu0PGg2ki9xx dev-myApp_me.com    /   2024-05-20T13:18:29.482Z    41          Lax     Medium  
name    USER_TESTER .hotmail.com    /   2023-07-10T23:20:45.525Z    12                  Medium  
_ga GA1.2.745112475.1669103969  .hotmail.com    /   2024-06-22T08:08:46.910Z    29                  Medium
```

As you can see, the first cookie has no name, I don't know why this happens. In the settings part I have Microsoft configured correctly and I also have this: SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True